# Changing module variables after import

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, circular-reference

SO pyton gurus! I've just found an astonishing phenomenon that I don't understand. The problem can be best shown as code:

```
#== kid.py ==#
import dad

def spam ():
    dad.spam()


#== dad.py ==#
import kid

x = 1
print "body", x

x = 2
def spam ():
    print "spam", x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 3
    spam()
    kid.spam()
    print "main", x
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3. Can you guess the output of `python dad.py`? The answer is (I wish SO had a spoiler shading tag) `body 1 body 1 spam 3 spam 2 main 3`. So could you  explain

1. Why is `body 1` printed twice?
2. How can `dad.x != kid.dad.x` be?
3. If I really need to make the two modules import each other, how can I modify it to get `kid.dad.x` properly updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because loading dad.py as the `__main__` module is independent of importing dad.py as the `dad` module.
2. See my answer to 1.
3. Import `__main__` instead if you *must*. But in general, *don't try this*. Find another way to accomplish your tasks (e.g. classes).

Printing `__name__` at the top of dad.py will illustrate this.

Comment: A-ha, ``__main__`` was the secret! Then I'll run it as module. Thanks heavens!