# Importing modules: __main__ vs import as module

Tags: python, module, python-import, python-module

To preface, I think I may have figured out how to get this code working (based on [Changing module variables after import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242417/changing-module-variables-after-import)), but my question is really about why the following behavior occurs so I can understand what to not do in the future.

I have three files.  The first is mod1.py:

```
# mod1.py

import mod2

var1A = None

def func1A():
    global var1
    var1 = 'A'
    mod2.func2()

def func1B():
    global var1
    print var1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1A()
```

Next I have mod2.py:

```
# mod2.py

import mod1

def func2():
    mod1.func1B()
```

Finally I have driver.py:

```
# driver.py

import mod1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod1.func1A()
```

If I execute the command `python mod1.py` then the output is `None`.  Based on the link I referenced above, it seems that there is some distinction between `mod1.py` being imported as `__main__` and `mod1.py` being imported from `mod2.py`.  Therefore, I created `driver.py`.  If I execute the command `python driver.py` then I get the expected output: `A`.  I sort of see the difference, but I don't really see the mechanism or the reason for it.  How and why does this happen?  It seems counterintuitive that the same module would exist twice.  If I execute `python mod1.py`, would it be possible to access the variables in the `__main__` version of `mod1.py` instead of the variables in the version imported by `mod2.py`?

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a favor if you refactor to eliminate the circular import.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `__name__` variable always contains the name of the module, *except* when the file has been loaded into the interpreter as a script instead. *Then* that variable is set to the string `'__main__'` instead.

After all, the script is then run as the main file of the whole program, everything else are modules imported directly or indirectly by that main file. By testing the `__name__` variable, you can thus detect if a file has been imported as a module, or was run directly.

Internally, modules are given a namespace dictionary, which is stored as part of the metadata for each module, in `sys.modules`. The main file, the executed script, is stored in that same structure as `'__main__'`.

But when you import a file as a module, python first looks in `sys.modules` to see if that module has already been imported before. So, `import mod1` means that we first look in `sys.modules` for the `mod1` module. It'll create a new module structure with a namespace if `mod1` isn't there yet.

So, if you both run `mod1.py` as the main file, *and* later import it as a python module, it'll get *two* namespace entries in `sys.modules`. One as `'__main__'`, then later as `'mod1'`. These two namespaces are completely separate. Your global `var1` is stored in `sys.modules['__main__']`, but `func1B` is looking in `sys.modules['mod1']` for `var1`, where it is `None`.

But when you use `python driver.py`, `driver.py` becomes the `'__main__'` main file of the program, and `mod1` will be imported just once into the `sys.modules['mod1']` structure. This time round, `func1A` stores `var1` in the `sys.modules['mod1']` structure, and that's what `func1B` will find.

Comment: Would this be OK then? `if __name__ == '__main__': sys.modules['mod1'] = sys.modules['__main__']; func1A()`

Comment: @Kos: I would not do that, I think you'll find that a whole lot of assumptions will break. Avoid using modules as scripts instead.

Comment: I have been using `if __name__ == '__main__':` to write a testing routine for each of my modules within the module.  Is there a good way to continue this practice, or should I write testing routines as functions then have a driver in a separate file that does nothing but import the module to be testing and call the testing routine?

Comment: @Brendan: convention uses a `tests.py` module or a `tests` package, using `unittests` as the framework.

Comment: Pleae can you briefly explain why global var1 is stored in sys.modules['__main__'], but func1B is looking in sys.modules['mod1'] for var1

Comment: @variable: because `mod1.func1B()` was called, so the *copy of the function in `mod1` is being used*. Functions use the globals in their own module object. Note that there is also a `__main__.func1B()` function, which is connected to the `__main__` globals.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. The issue here is that the value is set in the __main__ namespace. But mod2 function is accessing it from mod1 namespace

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a practical solution for using a module optionally as main script - supporting consistent cross-imports:

## Solution 1:

See e.g. in Python's pdb module, how it is run as a script by importing itself when executing as `__main__` (at the end) :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""A Python debugger."""
# (See pdb.doc for documentation.)
import sys
import linecache

...

# When invoked as main program, invoke the debugger on a script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pdb
    pdb.main()
```

Just I would recommend to reorganize the `__main__` startup to the beginning of the script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""A Python debugger."""
# When invoked as main program, invoke the debugger on a script
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    ##assert os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0] == 'pdb'
    import pdb
    pdb.main()
    sys.exit(0)

import linecache
...
```

This way the module body is not executed twice - which is "costly", undesirable and sometimes critical.

## Solution 2:

In rarer cases it is desirable to expose the actual script module `__main__` even directly as the actual module alias (`mod1`):

```
# mod1.py    
import mod2

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # use main script directly as cross-importable module 
    _mod = sys.modules['mod1'] = sys.modules[__name__]
    ##_modname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__)))[0]
    ##_mod = sys.modules[_modname] = sys.modules[__name__]
    func1A()
```

Known drawbacks:

- `reload(_mod)` fails
- pickle'ed classes would need extra mappings for unpickling (`find_global` ..)