# Share a singleton across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton

Given two modules, main and x with the following contents:

main:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls._instance.x = 10
        return cls._instance
uvw = Singleton()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(id(uvw))
    uvw.x += 10
    print(uvw.x)
    import x
```

and x, respectively:

```
import main

print(id(main.uvw))
print(main.uvw.x)
```

I would now expect that executing main would yield the same IDs and the value twenty in both instances, but what I get is this:

```
$ python main.py
140592861777168
20
140592861207504
10
```

Is there any way I can ensure that `uvw` is the same object at both places?

Comment: Note that the entire point of your `__new__` method is to prevent you from needing to access `main.uvw`, since `Singleton()` is guaranteed to return the same instance each time anyway.

Comment: So `main` is calling `x` which is calling `main`...? This is a recipe for confusion/disaster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing modules: \_\_main\_\_ vs import as module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181559/importing-modules-main-vs-import-as-module)

Comment: You are both using the `__main__` and the `x` module, which are separate namespaces. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python loads each module by name once (unless `reload(module)` is called). If you run `main.py`, the module is `__main__` (try printing `uvw.__class__.__module__`). When `x` imports `main`, the module called `main` is being loaded for the first time.

If you defined `uvw` in a third module, or in `x` -- as long as it is imported in the same way into `__main__` and `x` -- it would be the same object.

Answer (score 8):

I reckon the problem is that your `Singleton` class is somehow being reloaded, and thus loses its `_instance` field in the second module.

---

I think this will work:

`singleton.py`:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls._instance.x = 10
        return cls._instance
```

`a.py`:

```
from singleton import Singleton
uvw = Singleton()
print(id(uvw))
uvw.x += 10
print(uvw.x)
```

`b.py`:

```
from singleton import Singleton
uvw = Singleton()
print(id(uvw))
uvw.x += 10
print(uvw.x)
```

`main.py`

```
import a
import b
```

Comment: I don't really want to split my program further up... that would be kinda last resort for me :)

Comment: If your code has to import the main module from another file, something suspicious is going on.

Comment: See the dupe, @Eric; `sys.modules['__main__']` *is* different from `sys.modules['x']`.

Comment: @csde_rats Then put that singleto into the `x` module, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problem is that `main` is loaded twice when it's executed from the command line, one time as `__main__` and the second time when imported by x as `main`.

I found a very evil hack to circumvent the second load:

```
sys.modules["main"] = sys.modules["__main__"]
```

Separating the main module and the singleton class is not favorable in my case.

Comment: To avoid evil hack you could define `uvw` in a module that is not executed as a script and then just import that module in you main script