# Flask not finding routes in imported modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm having a problem with Flask wherein routes declared in imported modules are not be registered and always result in a 404. I am running the latest version Flask on Python 2.7.

I have the following directory structure:
[image]
run.py has the following code:
    from flask import Flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

import views.home

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

home.py has the following code:

```
from run import app


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return "test"
```

When I run `run.py` the route declared in `home.py` (http://localhost:5000/test) always returns a 404 even though `run.py` imports `views.home`. The root view (http://localhost:5000) declared in `run.py` works fine.

I have written a function that prints out all the registered routes and /test is not in there ([get a list of all routes defined in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317536/get-a-list-of-all-routes-defined-in-the-app)).

Any idea why?

Comment: try to just use `import views`

Comment: that didn't work, but it did spur me on to switching the import to `from views.home import *`, which did work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have discovered that switching the import statement in `run.py` from

```
import views.home
```

to

```
from views.home import *
```

makes everything work, which gave me the clue as to why the modules are not being registered using `import views.home`.

Basically, when `run.py` is run as a script it is given the name `__main__` and this is the name given to the module in `sys.modules` ([Importing modules: __main__ vs import as module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181559/importing-modules-main-vs-import-as-module))

Then when I import app from `run.py` in `views.home.py` a new instance of `run.py` is registered in `sys.modules` with the name `run`. As this point, the reference to `app` in `run.py` and `views.home.py` are two different references hence the routes not being registered.

The solution was to move the creation of the `app` variable out of `run.py` and in to a separate python file (I called it `web_app.py`) that is imported into `run.py`. This guarantees that the Flask `app` variable declared inside `web_app.py` is the always referenced correctly wherever `web_app.py` is imported.

So `run.py` now looks like this:

```
from web_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and `web_app.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import view.home
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was literally struggling for the past 3 hours.

Comment: your suggestion really worked for me. Thank you :=)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by reorganizing your code as it is described here [Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/), but it is more recommended to divide them into smaller groups where each group is implemented with the help of a blueprint. For a gentle introduction into this topic refer to the Modular Applications with Blueprints chapter of the documentation.

- [Modular Applications with Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/)