# Flask fails to register routes using 'import x.y' but works with 'from x.y import *'?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

As stated in [Flask not finding routes in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874629/flask-not-finding-routes-in-imported-modules?noredirect=1#comment53582406_32874629) I have a very simple Flask application in Python 2.7 that wasn't working when my routes were defined in a different module.

To recap, I have `run.py` at the top-level, which declares the Flask `app` variable and then imports the `views.home` module where the views are defined.

I have discovered that if I switch the import statement in `run.py` from:

```
import views.home
```

to

```
from views.home import *
```

everything works.

Why is that? As far as I can tell (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) there isn't any functional different between the two imports that should impact the behaviour of Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work out what is going on (as per [Flask not finding routes in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874629/flask-not-finding-routes-in-imported-modules/32882527#32882527))

Basically, when `run.py` is run as a script it is given the name `__main__` and it is registered in `sys.modules` as `__main__` (as per [Importing modules: __main__ vs import as module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181559/importing-modules-main-vs-import-as-module))

Then when I import `app` from `run.py` in `views.home.py`, python fails to find the `run` module in `sys.modules` (because it is called `__main__`) and creates a new instance of `run.py` and registers it in `sys.modules` with the name `run`.

At this point there are two instances of the `run` module in `sys.modules` and, as a result, two instances of the `app` variable.

`views.home.py` registers its routes with one instance of `app` and `run.py` starts the other instance of `app`, so `views.home.py`'s routes are never used.

The reason that

```
from views.home import *
```

works is because it creates references to all of the `views.home` functions in the `__main__` module (as per [`from ... import` vs `import .`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import)) which results in `views.home.py`'s routes being registered with the instance of the `app` variable thatr `run.py` starts.

Answer (score 0):

When importing with `import views.home`, in the place where you are using the views, are you using

```
views.home.somefunction()
```

or are you using:

```
somefunction()
```

?

The second one will only work when doing `from views.home import *`, as this will place all the stuff on views.home on the global namespace.

Comment: No, I'm not using `views.home.somefunction()` or `somefunction()`. `view.home` has a whole bunch of functions marked up with with `@app.route`  Flask attribute and Flask does not seem to process these when I use `import views.home`. I would have thought they would be processed as the action of importing the module results in in being processed

Comment: I finally worked out why I was seeing this behaviour. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874629/flask-not-finding-routes-in-imported-modules/32882527#32882527

Comment: awesome, the issue was a lot more complex than I initially though, but good learnings there, thanks for posting